# bootstrap 4 navbar border bottom color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

A lot of searching, but without result. How to change the border-bottom color of the navbar in Bootstrap 4

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
....
</nav>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is no border on the bottom of the Bootstrap 4 navbar. Are you using Bootstrap 3?

Comment: A lot, normal css and the border classes of bootstrap 4

Comment: Post all of the code... the CSS you've tried too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This

```
 <style>
        .navbar
        {
            border-bottom:5px solid #000;
        }
      </style>
```

In the place of #000  put your colour

Comment: i made a mistake i suppose, the simple sollution is the right answer....